# Как перенести правильно

Tags: перенос

Можно ли так перенести слово: "наст-роился"?

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли так перенести слово: "наст-роился"?

В настоящее время можно и *наст-роился*. Но лучше, по возможности, использовать такие переносы: *на-строился, настро-ился, настроил-ся.*

[**Правилами 1956 года**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/141-perenos) перенос *наст-роился* не допускался. См.:

> **§ 119…**
>
> <...>
>
> 5. **При переносе слов с приставками нельзя оставлять в конце строки при приставке начальную часть корня, не составляющую слога.**

В [**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97) такое ограничение снято. См.:

> **§ 217.** Группа неодинаковых согласных букв в середине слова, входящих в корень или образующих стык корня и суффикса, может быть разбита
>   переносом любым образом, напр.: *се-стра, сес-тра* и *сест-ра;
>   це-нтральный, цен-тральный* и *цент-рольный; ро-ждение* и *рож-дение;
>   де-тство, дет-ство, детс-тво* и *детст-во; шу-мный* и *шум-ный.*
>
> **Если же в группе согласных** часть принадлежит приставке или если **вся группа начинает вторую часть приставочного слова, предпочтительно
>   учитывать членение слова на значимые части.** Предпочтительные
>   переносы: *под-бить, под-бросить, **при-слать**, от-странить.* **Допустимые**
>   **переносы**: *по-дбить, подб-росить; **прис-лать**; отс-транить* и
>   *отст-ранить.*